# "Invert" a startswith DataFrame selection in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas allows `startswith` selections on a `DataFrame`, such as:

```
query = "Ali"
people[people.Name.str.startswith(query)]
```

... which might result in something like

```
Name
Ali
Alice
Alicia
Alistair
...
```

However, I would like to invert the inputs in the selection, to find rows where the `input` starts with a value in the `DataFrame`.

Something like:

```
query = "Ali"
people[query.startswith(people.Name)]
```

This might select names `Al` and `Ali` for example.

This code obviously doesn't work, and this doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do with this example, but it's what I would like to achieve with my data.

Anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: What are you expected to get? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: `people[people.FullName.apply(lambda s: input_str.startswith(s))]`? Also, I renamed `input` to `input_str` because `input` is a builtin function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will update question shortly

Comment: I wonder if there's an argument for making this a pandas function. It's not needed in pure Python because you can just do `s2.startswith(s1)`, but that's not the case here, when `s1`  is a Series and `s2` is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preparation

```
import pandas as pd

people = pd.DataFrame()
people["FullName"] = ["Alice Cooper", "Ali","Aloy"]

input_ = "Alice"
```

---

Alternative 1: [Boolean-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
people[[input_.startswith(i) for i in people.FullName]] # passes [False, True, False]
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 937 µs per loop

---

Alternative 2 **(thanks @Abdou)**: Invoke function on values of Series using [.apply() and lambda](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

```
people[people.FullName.apply(lambda s: input_.startswith(s))]
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.38 ms per loop

---

Outputs:

```
FullName
1   Ali
```